# Is it possible to install installer on laptop disk in order to install Linux to USB? How?

Tags: system-installation, dual-boot, solus

So usually when we want a portable USB we'll prepare two USB sticks, one for the installer, one for where you install Linux.

But now, I want to install [solus](https://solus-project.com/home/) but only got a 128GB USB which is used to install the Linux **on it**. So now I'm wondering, is it possible to split about 16GB from local disk from my desktop to put the installer in the disk, boot from it, then install Linux to my USB stick.

If yes, how can I achieve it? Should I use [rufus](http://rufus.akeo.ie) to burn iso like what I did USB installer? Or directly use the burn function built-in Windows 10?

Answer (score 0):

You can use grub to boot ISO images.

https://www.howtogeek.com/196933/how-to-boot-linux-iso-images-directly-from-your-hard-drive/